# PowerShell Stop-Service/Start-Service not working on a specific server

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have three servers, let's call them *Deploy1*, *Deploy2*, *Target*.
All servers are running Windows Server 2008R2, fully updated.
A domain user, *admin1*, is configured as administrator on all servers, and this is the user I'm running all the commands with.

The following command works on *Deploy1*:

```
Get-Service "MyService" -ComputerName Target | Stop-Service
```

When running the same command on *Deploy2*, the command fails with the following message:

> Cannot find any service with service name 'MyService'.

On *Deploy2*, the following command works, and displays the service and its status.

`Get-Service "MyService" -ComputerName Target`

Now, I know there are other ways to stop/start services via PowerShell, but I like this one as it automatically waits for the server to actually stop/start.

So what could be wrong with *Deploy2*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell v2.0 has a bug (feature?) in how the object returned by Get-Service is implemented. It does not actually set the ComputerName property correctly. Because of this, it can only affect local services. If you upgrade to [Windows Management Framework 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595) (and consequently Powershell v3) the bug is fixed and will work correctly.

Comment: Thanks, apparently on Deploy1 a service in the same name was deployed locally, and therefore the command worked (although it stopped the local service instead of the remote one).

Answer (score 2):

Does this work? If not, is there an error produced?

```
(Get-Service "MyService" -ComputerName Target).Stop()
```